# Could the review-suggested-edits pages let me go back to where I was before?

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

When browsing something on SO I get regular notifications that there are a number of suggested edits pending review, and I routinely click them and dutifully do some reviewing.

When I am done, I'd like resume my browsing where I left off, but I can only do this by back-clicking my browser through all the suggested edits I have reviewed.

Could the review pages have a "back-to-where-I-was" button?

Comment: Hold the back button to reveal your browsing history.

Comment: @JanDvorak or right-click it.

Comment: Never knew that! Frightening what I don't know.

Comment: Alternatively, right click the edit notification and open the queue in a new tab or window.

Comment: While that solves the problem temporarily, is there any reason that SO can't remember where you were when you clicked the review button, and have a "return" button that will bring you back there when you are done (or automatically redirect you after handling the last edit in that queue)?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263657/245360

Answer (score -2):

I disagree, sorry. This is a task for your browser, not for a website.