# Return to post after reviewing a suggested edit on an own post

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

This request originates from here: [Why ask me to approve an edit to my own post *and* when I don't have the rep to?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263633/245360).

When someone suggests an edit on my own post, I get a notification asking to review the item.

After the edit is reviewed, it takes me to the next suggested item to review. For users having less than 2000 reputation, it says this:

> [image: lt 2k]

This confuses people, since they think the review wasn't successful.

Is it possible to go back to the post which was reviewed in this case, instead of the above screen? Maybe this is useful for 2K+ users too, but I don't mind if it is kept for them to encourage reviewing posts.

Comment: I would go with simply hiding the Next button for <2k users.

Comment: That would be an okay option too.

Comment: +1 Additionally, even for users with 2K rep, they are not reviewing in general, they were actioning their own post and so should logically be taken back to their post after reviewing. I'm all for encouraging people to review, but not with a method which is likely not going to encourage them and just risks their being confused/frustrated.

Comment: If you are a 2K user you probably know your way around. If not, it is time to learn.

Comment: Their "knowing their way around" wasn't my point, it was about being taken somewhere illogical - "frustrated". Regardless of rep, moderator, staff, once you've reviewed an edit on your own post, it would be better to be taken to that post. You can then view it, check the edit looks ok on the actual post, etc :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, yes you should.

An easier way would be replacing the "Next" button with a "Return to Page" button which redirects you to your most recent page (the one before reviewing). This would make a lot more sense, and the "Next" button will only be shown to people with 2k rep and/or have more own posts to review suggested edits.

If the change is too complicated for the developers, they could instead change the text to something like:

> Thank you for reviewing. You need 2k rep to review suggested edits on ***other people's posts***.

So the first line is spot tell the user that the initial review was successful and nothing went wrong. The second line tells the user that he/she needs 2k rep to review suggested edits made on ***other people's posts***, which is actually accurate since you could review your own posts for suggested edits. The bold was just added for emphasis.

So yes, yes you should.