# When I review an edit to one of my own posts, please don't send me to the queue afterwards

Tags: feature-request, review

I just had the following experience:

1. Got notification of proposed edit to one of my posts
2. Approved said edit.
3. Was shown the next random edit in the review queue

Folks, I never, ever, want to see a review queue again. I have had it with the insulting 'stop, look, and listen' message arriving over and over due to crap in the audits. I didn't ask to review the queue, I asked to review one particular edit brought to my attention by the inbox. When I finish that task, I should be returned to where I came from.

Comment: I think a better solution would be to fix the audits so review is friendlier and better-populated.

Comment: Related, or exact dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263657/241919

Answer (score 2):

This is from one of my [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263664/278543) about a related question on suggested edits:

> An easier way would be replacing the "Next" button with a "Return to Page" button which redirects you to your most recent page (the one before reviewing)...

So instead of replacing, we could add a "Return to Page" button where it sends you back to your previous page before you reviewed your own post(s)'(s) suggested edit(s). This should be helpful, especially for people who don't want to review anymore, like you!